# RViz Camera View is up-side down

Tags: ros, kinect, camera, asus, pr2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

We have mounted an Kinect (to be precise an Asus Xtion Live Pro) sensor up-side down onto our PR2. We added the appropriate config (camera frames) into the robot.xml (via the python script provided at the ROS wiki).
Furthermore the TF (rpy angles) were modified and it was verified that the point cloud was indeed at the right orientation (regarding the robot) with RViz.

Nevertheless the camera view (2D) in RViz is still up-side down. Does anyone have a clue why?

Cheers,
Sebastian

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/29664/rviz-camera-view-is-up-side-down/) by [Sebastian Rockel](https://answers.ros.org/users/1966/sebastian-rockel/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2012-03-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The Camera display in RViz shows just what the image stream contains (which in this case is upside-down), plus other 3D data if the alpha is less than 1.0, as Felix mentions.  That way you can see the other 3D data upside-down as well.

If you want the image stream to be rotated so that it's "up" vector matches your own personal "up" vector, you need to have a ROS node subscribe to the image stream, rotate it, and re-publish it.  The [image_rotate](http://www.ros.org/wiki/image_rotate) package has a node for this.

---

Originally posted by [hersh](https://answers.ros.org/users/97/hersh/) with karma: 1351 on 2012-03-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1